# Javafx ControlsFX - Open two dialogs one overlapping the other dialog

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I am trying to open new `dialog` on click of a `button` which is inside the `dialog window`.
I am getting the below error.

```
Key already associated with a running event loop: javafx.scene.Scene@57eef8ee
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
at org.controlsfx.dialog.LightweightDialog.show(LightweightDialog.java:224)
at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:323)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. File an bug report at issues.controlsfx.org

Comment: I'm not sure that would be a bug.  Dialogs are usually modal, so opening a second modal dialog from inside a modal dialog seems like it might give that kind of error.  The documentation does say that you can make your dialog non-modal.
Stacking dialogs doesn't sound like a good design, though.